# is there a way to configure webex to automatically mute a participant when they start typing?

Tags: webex

I would like to know if we can configure webex session to mute participants audio while they are typing.

WebEx should automatically detect typing noise and mute that audio.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an option to to configure webex automatically to detect if a participant is typing and mute their audio